# How to make button reappear?

Tags: html

I have the following html code for a button that disappears after you click it. How should I edit it to make the button reappear after a function is completed.

//< button onClick="start(0);this.style.display = 'none'">Generate Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an ID to your button. At the end of the other function set it's display to block.

```
<button id="myBtn" onClick="start(0); this.style.display='none'">Generate Code</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").style = "display: block;";
</script>
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vxx7vqxg/

Comment: You're welcome! Here is your updated code http://jsfiddle.net/sLggoyqn/9/

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the function, set display to its original status.

//< button id = "btn" onClick="this.style.display = 'none';start(0)">Generate code

start() {
.....
.....
document.getElementById('btn').style.display = initial;
}